# defining functions on-the-fly in C++

Tags: c++, interface, c++-cli, implementation

In C++, is it possible to implement one Class's function(s) within another (unrelated except by dependency) Class's function(s)?  The behavior I'm looking for can be achieved in Java using abstract methods and/or interfaces which are implemented within anonymous inner-classes like so:

```
Interface IFoo{

public void doFoo();

}

Class Bar {
private IFoo impl;
public Bar(IFoo implArg){
    impl = implArg;
}


}
static void main(String[] args) {
Bar myBar = new Bar(new IFoo(){
    @Override
    public void doFoo(){
        System.out.println("hello foo impl!");
    }
});
}
```

Can this same effect be achieved in C++ and, if so, how?  The use case I have in mind is on-the-fly definition of rules something like the following:

AbstractRule.h

```
#ifndef _ABSTRACT_RULE_H_
#define _ABSTRACT_RULE_H_

#include <stdio.h>

class AbstractRule{
private:

public:
AbstractRule();
~AbstractRule();
void enforceAbstractRule();
};

#endif
```

AbstractRule.cpp

```
#include "AbstractRule.h"
AbstractRule::AbstractRule(){
}
AbstractRule::~AbstractRule(){
}

void AbstractRule::enforceAbstractRule(){
printf("placeholder impl of enforceRule-- should not see this in production");
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "AbstractRule.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
AbstractRule myRule;
//do something here so that myRule.enforceAbstractRule() call prints "enforced 
    //myRule!"
myRule.enforceAbstractRule();
}
```

The question is, what do I need to do at the 'do something here...' comment to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Lambdas are good for on-the-fly functions. Also, your include guard name is reserved.

Comment: I've heard of lambdas, but have never used them-- could you provide an example usage or link to a good comprehensive tutorial?

Comment: C++/CLI doesn't have lambdas yet.  Why is this question tagged `c++-cli` anyway?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like an instance of the XY problem to me. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JerryCoffin the actual implementation is a good deal more complicated-- I just wanted to provide a C++ wrapper for the functionality I'm looking for

Comment: @CCJ, A function object to multiply two ints would be `auto f = [](int a, int b) {return a * b;};`. There are quite a few good resources that are easily googled with that term.

Comment: @chris "function object", eh?  I'll look into that, thanks!

Comment: @CCJ, Ah, yes. That just means you can use it like a function. It's what you store the lambda (among other things) into if you don't want to use it right away, or more than once. It would be used via `f(2, 3);`. You can also forget the storage and create the lambda right where you want it. Printing a container *could* be `std::for_each(std::begin(cont), std::end(cont), [](int element) {std::cout << element << ' ';});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has something called "Nameless classes", which is what your example uses - note that your "concept" is slightly "wrong" in that you are not actually declaring a function "on the fly", you are declaring a new class "on the fly".

In C++ all classes have to have a name [1].

So, for what you want to do, you need to declare a class that extends the baseclass:

```
class MyRule : public Rule
{
   void enforceRule();
};


void MyRule::enforceRule()
{
   ... stuff goes here ... 
}
```

You can of course place the declaration `inline` inside the class declaration as well. But for this to be possible to use, you need to give it a name.

Now, your main will have:

```
MyRule myRule;
```

[Or, more likely, you call a factory function that selects the "correct" rule class, creates a new object, and return a pointer to that object]

[1] Not strictly true always, but for this particular use, you do need a class-name.

Comment: hmm, okay that could do the job.  I would want to mark enforceRule() and ~AbstractRule() in the AbstractRule class virtual in this case though, right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a factory, for certain. But in general, if you intend of inheriting and overriding functions, it's a good way to design things.

Comment: that's it. The java nameless class definition is syntactic sugar, In the end that class will be given a generated name. In C++ one needs to simply hide the class definition to get a similar effect.

Comment: note that there's one tricky aspect to it, namely when the anonymous class definition refers to values from the scope where the definition occurs. Your example doesn't have that feature, but it's a possibility iirc. The solution is to make these values parameters to the class constructor, or make them template parameters, in which case the hidden class must be a template.

Answer (score 2):

If all you're interested is a small function definable inline, you will want to look at std::function and lambda support added in C++11.  If that's not an option, you may be able to get by with some boost library, but you'd likely need to define a number of named throwaway classes.